# How can you override a flash message from devise set in :require_no_authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I added 2 factor authentication to my application by calling a :prepend_before_action before the session create method of devise. This calls a `sign_in` of the user before the session is created and after the 2factor token is verified.

In Devise, there's a helper, [`:require_no_authentication`](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/c82e4cf47b02002b2fd7ca31d441cf1043fc634c/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L102) that runs before the create action which sets a flash message and does a redirect if the user is signed in.

Is there a way to still run the helper while not setting the flash message or customizing it before the redirect happens in case it's run after my 2factor was successful?

Answer (score 2):

[require_no_authentication](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/c82e4cf47b02002b2fd7ca31d441cf1043fc634c/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L102) will call [set_flash_message](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/c82e4cf47b02002b2fd7ca31d441cf1043fc634c/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L157-L159) and `set_flash_message` only set flash if the message presents, so you could avoid the flash message by replace with an empty message.

in your case, that message is `devise.failure.already_authenticated`, now if you're not gonna use that message any more (`2factor mode`) then you could delete it directly in `devise.en.yml`, otherwise, if you want to keep it, just ignore only in `2factor mode`, you could override the method `set_flash_message` as below

```rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
 # ...
 def set_flash_message(key, kind, options = {})
  unless key == :alert && kind == 'already_authenticated'
   super 
  end
 end
end
```

however, above code is hardcode and you maybe need to ignore/override more messages in `2factor`, you can add a `I18n::Backend` for `2factor` and add it on top of the `I18n::Backend::Chain` (no need to override `set_flash_message`)

```rb
# config/initializers/i18n_2factor.rb
TwoFactor_Backend = I18n::Backend::KeyValue.new({})
TwoFactor_Backend.store_translations(:en, 
 devise: {
  failure: {
   already_authenticated: "",
   inactive: ""
  }
 }
)

I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::Chain.new(TwoFactor_Backend, I18n.backend)
```

In case you don't want `TwoFactor_Backend` effect other features, you can add a block that will only use `TwoFactor_Backend` one time:

```rb
# config/initializers/i18n_2factor.rb
# ...
def with_2factor
  begin
    I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::Chain.new(TwoFactor_Backend, I18n.backend)
    result = yield
  ensure
    I18n.backend.backends.shift # back to normal
  end
  result
end
```

now you can use it when you override `set_flash_message`, after that `I18n` will back to normal

```rb
def set_flash_message(key, kind, options = {})
 with_2factor do
  super
 end
end
```